# WPF Path duplication

Tags: wpf, optimization

The application that I'm currently working on contains a list of items, each item represents a message sent to the user from a variety of sources (twitter, facebook, email ect..)

Each item contains a small vector graphic (path) that helps the user identify what the source of the message was.

[image]

in order to get this vector image to properly appear on each item I've marked it's resource with the x:Shared="False" attribute which causes a new instance of the path to be created for every message.

This all works fine but I can't help feeling like creating multiple instances of the same path seems like a waste. I can't use a bitmap since the items change size so vector images are required.

**My question is this: Anyone got a better way to present multiple paths from the same resource without having to generate new instances of the path object?**

Comment: Consider storing the Path's Geometry as a resource, then referencing that resource from the Data property of your individual Path instances.

Comment: Using .Net Reflector it looks like the Shape (base for Path) clones the geometry if you set it's Stretch property to anything other than System.Windows.Media.Stretch.None which we have. I guess your idea means we only get 1 copy of the data per message instead of two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it is a bad design or implementation. `Path` is a `UIElement` and thus can have only one `Parent` ( that is the reason of make x:Shared = false) and if you want to have vector graphics then you have to use Path.
So each Parent will have its own child `UIElement` i.e. Path here.

Think of this in a way, if I have a form with multiple input controls for data input  and have multiple buttons to save each set of data. In this case I will have that many instances of Child Buttons even if all of them will just be saying "Save" on them. So I dont think having multiple instances of Path with similar geometry is a problem